# Python - Global not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, global

I'm currently working on a tkinter project. The code is shown below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font  as tkfont

background_colour = "#F0F0F0"

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title("CCNA Command Learner")
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.iconbitmap("favicon.ico")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (IntroPage, MainPage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("IntroPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()



class IntroPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file="IntroImage.gif")
        self.head_img = tk.Label(self, image=self.image,         background=background_colour)
        self.head_img.pack()

        self.label = tk.Label(self, bg=background_colour,
                          text="\nLearn essential commands for the CCNA exam\n\nPlease enter your name")
        self.label.pack()

        self.head_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.head_entry.pack()

        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.submit_button)
        self.submit.pack()

    def submit_button(self):
        global var_username
        self.controller.show_frame("MainPage")
        var_username = self.head_entry.get()




class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.introduction = tk.Label(self, text="Hello" + var_username)
        self.introduction.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

My problem is that in the submit_button method of my IntroPage class, I am trying to set a global variable so that my MainPage class can then access it. However, despite declaring it and setting it, I am still getting a NameError when accessing it in my MainPage class?

Comment: Follow your code line by line. `var_username` is never assigned to (and therefore never defined) before `IntroPage.submit_button` is called. When is that called? After everything is initialized and on screen. But `MainPage` is trying to access the variable in its *initializer*, before `submit_button` could ever be called.

Comment: Global variable is messy business. Generally avoid them and use instance attributes and methods. In your case, you can store the username on the app instance

Comment: Also, Python doesn't have a notion of declaration. The name exists as soon as you assign to it, and [not before](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TaEktbhEQ9OKSwEI0nPykxJzFFLyU4vjM0viUysyi0vAEgVFmXklGkqeJQpgsWJFhepaJb20/KLcxBINFOWammANKGIKtgrqxfm5qSUZmXnp6lxcECv//wcA).

Comment: @RamkishoreM There's not much practical difference between storing it globally on the module's single `Application` instance and storing it globally on the module. In particular, stuffing it into `Application` creates significant problems communicating the value around between the different classes.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, as you seem to use `global` incorrectly. It can make existing variable out of your scope visible and available for modification, like this:

```
a = 'test'

def f():
    global a
    a = 'edited'

f()
print(a)
```

Output:

```
>>> edited
```

You don't seem to declare variable with this name, hence the `NameError`. And again - `global` is not for creating global variables, it is for making them visible.

By the way, think twice before using globals in python, that usually indicates huge design problems. It's surely possible to refactor your code in a way that you won't need `global`.

Comment: How would you recommend I do this without using global?

Comment: @Sam, when in your program do you know username?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean sorry?

Comment: When do you get value for `var_username`?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need create it before MainPage in call stack.
Create it outside the IntroPage class, and initializing can stay where it is.